# Does tr need included in HTML table in there is one row

Tags: html

I am creating a table in html. The table only has one row
Is the correct syntax to put  and  even though its one row?
or should i just use  and .
What is the correct syntax for this or does it not matter?
thank you for clarifying.

Comment: A row is not a row unless you tag it as such. Any text within a table that has no tags will be flagged as an error.